# eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker - Retrieve multidate array using angularjs ng-model

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to get the selected array of dates when using `multidate` date picker, using `AngularJs` ng-model i only get the last selected date ; not all selected dates array.

I am using inline mode of date picker (https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) :

```
<div my-date-picker multidate="true" data-ng-model="row.dates">
```

Answer (score 1):

using method `getDates` will do this :

```
$(element).datepicker("getDates")
```